# several <ItemTemplate> in one ListView

Tags: asp.net, listview, itemtemplate

I saw a lot of examples of using ListView,but couldn't found simple,understandable example of using two (or more) ItemTemplates in one ListView (if it possible).I want to define them on .aspx page or to make programmatically,and,depending on my needs choose one of them (different templates for different binding data).Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve that you want two ItemTemplates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this would help you achieve what you want?
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2008/07/26/dynamically-loading-listview-templates.aspx

Also go through this post to have some insight as well
http://forums.asp.net/t/1699218.aspx/1?ListView+ItemCommand+event+not+working+with+Dynamic+Templates

Answer (score 0):

You can make one `<ItemTemplate>`with several panels inside, and then in code beind you make only one of them visible.