# One ListView Receiving Data from Multiple Class

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-fragments, custom-adapter

I am looking for something like this:
[several <ItemTemplate> in one ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772558/several-itemtemplate-in-one-listview).

But it was in .ASP and above my level.

---

What I need

---

Class Vitals:       vTime, BP, Heart Rate, Respirations per Minute, etc.

Class Medications:  mTime, RxName, RxRoute, RxDose, RxDoseUnit, etc.

Class Procedures: pTime, Intubation, IV insertion, Defibrillation, etc.

Classes Vitals, Medications and Procedures to be based on user input that inject in to a ListView (sorted chronologically). A "Many-to-One" if I may.

I've went through hours of "CustomAdapter & ListView" tutorials, code samples, walkthroughs.

---

Here is my current code (trashed and scattered) to show that I am actively working towards a solution:

```
/*
 * Created by SwaLayS on 2/19/2015.
 */

public class VitalAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<VitalItem> vitalData;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


public VitalAdapter(Context acontext, ArrayList<VitalItem> vitalData){
    this.vitalData=vitalData;
    layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(acontext);
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return vitalData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return vitalData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.vital_view_children,null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

    }


}
```

---

```
public class VitalView extends RelativeLayout {
private TextView vTimeTV;
// private TextView vPTATV;
private TextView vRateTV;
private TextView vOxySatTV;
private TextView vSysBPTV;
private TextView vDiaBPTV;
private TextView vRespRateTV;
private TextView vRespEffortTV;
//private TextView vMethodBPTV;

public static VitalView inflate(ViewGroup parent){
    VitalView vitalView = (VitalView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.vital_view,parent,false);
    return vitalView;
}

public VitalView(Context c){
    this(c,null);
}

public VitalView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    this(context, attrs,0);
}

public VitalView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
    super(context,attrs,defStyle);
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.vital_view_children, this,true);
    setupChildren();
}

private void setupChildren(){
    vTimeTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vTime);
 // vPTATV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vPTA);
    vRateTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vBPM);
    vOxySatTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vOsat);
    vSysBPTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vSystolic);
    vDiaBPTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vDiastolic);
    vRespRateTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vRespRate);
    vRespEffortTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vRespEffort);
 // vMethodBPTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vMethodBP

}
public void setVital(VitalItem vital){
   //vTimeTV.setText(vital.get);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class VitalItem {


private String vTime;
// private String vPTA;
private String vRate;
private String vOxySat;
private String vSysBP;
private String vDiaBP;
private String vRespRate;
private String vRespEffort;
// private String vMethodBP;


 public VitalItem(String Time, String Rate, String OxySat, String SysBP, String DiaBp, RespRate, String RespEffort){
    super();
    vTime=Time;
    // vPTA=PTA;
    vRate=Rate;
    vOxySat = OxySat;
    vSysBP = SysBP;
    vDiaBP = DiaBP;
    vRespRate = RespRate;
    vRespEffort=RespEffort;
    //vMethodBP=MethodBP;
}




public String getvTime() {
    return vTime;
}

public void setvTime(String vTime) {
    this.vTime = vTime;
}

// public String getvPTA() {
//      return vPTA;
// }

// public void setvPTA(String vPTA) {
//     this.vPTA = vPTA;
// }

public String getvRate() {
    return vRate;
}

public void setvRate(String vRate) {
    this.vRate = vRate;
}

public String getvOxySat() {
    return vOxySat;
}

public void setvOxySat(String vOxySat) {
    this.vOxySat = vOxySat;
}

public String getvSysBP() {
    return vSysBP;
}

public void setvSysBP(String vSysBP) {
    this.vSysBP = vSysBP;
}

public String getvDiaBP() {
    return vDiaBP;
}

public void setvDiaBP(String vDiaBP) {
    this.vDiaBP = vDiaBP;
}

public String getvRespRate() {
    return vRespRate;
}

public void setvRespRate(String vRespRate) {
    this.vRespRate = vRespRate;
}

public String getvRespEffort() {
    return vRespEffort;
}

public void setvRespEffort(String vRespEffort) {
    this.vRespEffort = vRespEffort;
}

// public String getvMethodBP() {
//    return vMethodBP;
//}

// public void setvMethodBP(String vMethodBP) {
//     this.vMethodBP = vMethodBP;
// 
    }


}
```

---

I'd appreciate any and everything;
I'm working on a NEMSIS . org project;
I may even be searching with the wrong search terms for what I need.

All help is appreciated

Comment: not clear elaborate more...what is your problem and what do you want to do ?

Comment: @Rohit, I want different user inputs from fragments to collect my treatment information for a patient... (A)vitals, (B)medications, and (C)procedures will ALL be on a "Treatment" listview. listed in various order based on user input (example as a paramedic I might Do vitals. Do procedure,  give medication, Do vitals) where each row comes ( row_a, row_b, row_c ) from my layout files.      I want 3 sources (arrays or adapters) to feed my main list.    What arrangement of custom lusy/listview adapters to I need to accomplish this dynamically?

Comment: i think you want to show all the items category wise....category wise means items of vitals then medications then procedures in a single listview...am i right ?

Comment: Rohit yes, that is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: For this you have to use section listview...try these tutorials...http://javatechig.com/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android

Comment: http://codetheory.in/android-dividing-listview-sections-group-headers/

Comment: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/02/24/listview-with-sections-in-android/

Comment: I never got back to thanking you @Rohit : Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you try the getViewTypeCount() method in adapter,

it can define different itemView for your different data types.

for your case  you need to define three layout items .

search some demos,it may help you .

Comment: Hey DavidLeen29; It seems that you have me on the right track; now I'm just struggling to nail it down properly.